# css file doesn't work on wahmpserver?

Tags: php, html, css, localhost

I've got a login form with css. When I open it from my whampserver (localhost) it doesn't display the css, but when I save it on my desktop and open it from their it does.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens.

[image: the login form]

pls don't down vote because it's obvious.

Comment: you should add your css in your `project_name` folder.

Comment: try to put you css file in the same directory as you php file, and use relative path or some link like (http://localhost/your-directory/stylesheet.css)[#] to link you style file to your html

Comment: I've never seen doctype declared like that. Why not just <!DOCTYPE html>? I also find it strange that you're using `  \ ` in your urls and not `/`. Perhaps its the document setup?

Comment: You can't access your local partition for a webserver based system.

Comment: @yvesdaxmaz  thnx for your reaction, unfurtunetly it didn't work. I changed my href to: localhost\php-login-minimal-master\views\main.css but it still doesn't display the css. When I implement "localhost\php-login-minimal-master\views\main.css" to my browser it does display the css file. So it is the right link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a local absolute path to your CSS file ("C:\Users\marij_000....").
Once you'll deploy your site to a different server it won't be able to access your local computer , thus, the CSS link will be broken.

Best Practice advice. Add a "css" folder to your project and place all the CSS files in that folder, then use a relative path to your files. For example:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">`

the first "/" state that the server will start the path from the project's root folder.

Comment: @Italy Gal it works!!! thnx a lot for your answer and clear explanation. I only got one problem: it doesn't display the image in the css file I added it with this code:body { background-image:url("typewriter-801921.jpg"); } the image is in the same directory, so it should work right? do you know why it doesn't?

Comment: Again, add the "/" to the image url.Also recommend to put the images on a different folder, for example "img" and then your url will look like this : "/img/your-image-name.jpg"